# Why Clojure doesn't follow the most common indentation style in java code?

Tags: java, clojure

I was looking at java code in Clojure. I found the indentation to be very strange to me.

I'm pretty used to the indentation style by http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#262. And most of the IDEs have configured auto-format in this way. Why doesn't Clojure follow this style?

UPDATE:

I meant the part of Clojure implemented in java e.g. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ARef.java

Comment: What do you mean by "Java code in Clojure"? Whether or not you are interoperating with Java, Clojure looks nothing at all like Java.  It uses a simple set of forms processed by a reader.  Java has a LOT more syntax.

Comment: @RayToal Sorry my question was confusing. I updated the question.

Comment: Ah, yes, the update to the question helped a lot.

Comment: @woodings I'd have to agree that it looks a bit weird, but probably the best way to find out is to go to #clojure and see if Rich shows up (or ask him on Twitter on something). You're not likely to find the answer here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code you are referring to uses the [Whitesmiths style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style) of brace indentation.

It is a matter of personal preference.  Nothing wrong with it, other than it is not very common.

Answer (score 0):

Why follow Java indentation style? Clojure follows Lisp.

Comment: I believe the OP's asking about the indentation of the Java portions of the official Clojure implementation - not about code that's written in Clojure.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks! You're right. I meant the java code in Clojure implementation.